# Sum values based on Timestamp for InfluxDb (Flux)

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2

I have data for executions running on different machines(Agents). The data is like:

| _time | AgentName | RunningSessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Agent1 | 1 |
| 002 | Agent1 | 4 |
| 003 | Agent1 | 10 |
| 004 | Agent1 | 12 |
| 005 | Agent1 | 15 |
| 001 | Agent2 | 1 |
| 002 | Agent2 | 5 |
| 003 | Agent2 | 8 |
| 004 | Agent2 | 10 |
| 005 | Agent2 | 15 |

For the above data, my plot is like this(showing two colors for different Agents)

[image]

I need to combine the data based on **_time** so that the final data is like:

| _time | RunningSessions |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2 |
| 002 | 9 |
| 003 | 18 |
| 004 | 22 |
| 005 | 30 |

What would be an optimal flux query to join the source data to produce the sum of RunningSessions based on time.

**Note:** There is a complexity here for data missing for a time instant from an Agent. Suppose for time=006, Agent1 is having 35 sessions, but Agent2 hasn't reported any change, so for time=006 Agent2 must still be running the last() 30 sessions.

This is my current query:

```
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "RunningSessions")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "totalSessionsCount")
  |> group(columns: ["_time"])
  |> sum(column: "_value")
  |> group()
```

**Update (1)**: Adding current Table view &  query
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the time precision of milliseconds which was not being shown in the UI, but it was there due to which I couldn't group with the _time column.

> truncateTimeColumn(unit: 1s)

[image]

```
from(bucket: "${bucket}")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "RunningSessions")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "totalSessionsCount")
  |> truncateTimeColumn(unit: 1s)
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 5s, fn: last, createEmpty: true)
  |> group(columns: ["_time"])
  |> sum(column: "_value")
  |> group()
  |> yield(name: "Total VU Load")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with flux, but you can sum your time series at Grafana.

Go to panel edit mode > Transform:

- Add "Add field from calculation" transformation,
- select `Calculation`: `Total`,
- enable option `Replace all fields`.

Comment: Doesn't works. Problem is due to the complexity explained in the *Note* above. For a timeinstant say 006 there was no update from Agent2. But at 005, Agent2 was running 30 sessions. But when I transform it using Total, it says Agent1=35 & Agent2=null and therefore=> Total=35